# Looking for advice on effective soundproofing of basement workshop

Tags: plywood, cnc, noise

I have a question that might not be directly related to woodworking, but I'm facing a significant challenge and concern. I would greatly appreciate your guidance.

I live in Windsor, Ontario, and after a 10-year hiatus, I'm eager to resume my woodworking hobby, although not as a profession. The issue is that I reside in a quiet area, and I'm restricted in terms of the noise I can make. Specifically, I live in a semi-detached house with a shared wall with my neighbour.

I'm considering purchasing an Avid CNC and setting it up in the basement, in one of the rooms. I plan to add one or two layers of "acoustic drywall" to minimize noise, but I'm uncertain about the extent to which these drywalls can reduce noise.

I'm curious if anyone else has encountered a similar situation and would be willing to share their thoughts.

Comment: Weird... Usually I tell people at [diy.se] to come here for woodworking advice. In this case, though, I'd suggest you visit there and look at the `sound-proofing` tag for loads of info about noise reduction and full-on sound proofing.

Comment: One thing you may want to check into is the expected dB level of the machines you're interested in.

Comment: I wasn't aware that we had a dedicated channel for home improvement. Thanks for informing me! To be honest, I've had experience with CNC machines before. Water-cooled spindles are quieter than air-cooled ones, but the noise during cutting depends on the density of the materials.

Comment: @FreeMan, do you want to briefly summarise some of the most relevant Q&As from DIY into an Answer here? Rather than us migrating this to there, it could make this our cornerstone soundproofing Question.

Comment: Good idea, but... no. There are 286 in the `sound-proofing` tag and "only" 24 in `sound-deadening` (which probably needs to be merged with `sound-proofing`).  That's a lot of summary...

Comment: OK, I did it anyway, @Graphus, but it doesn't answer the question asked, so technically, it's low-quality...

Comment: @FreeMan, I think it goes beyond answering the Q as asked, as that's more important than what was asked in a big-picture way. And given the chances of any Answer here (in real time) being forthcoming from someone who has first hand experience are next to nil.....

Answer (score 2):

The basics of sound proofing are (as I understand it from reading through [questions tagged "sound-proofing" at Home Improvement](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-proofing)):

- Physical separation

  - Noise on one side of a wall will travel through the studs that make up the wall.
  - Sound proof walls are often constructed with a 2x6 top/bottom plate with 2x4s staggered every 8", one on one room's side, the next on the other room's side. This arrangement puts a stud every 16" on each side of the walls to allow for normal spacing for hanging drywall. This minimizes the physical connection between the rooms.
  - Funny thing - I don't know what's done at the end of the wall where both sides need a stud to support the end of the drywall. Further research on this would be necessary.
- Mass

  - The more mass there is, the harder it is for sound to travel through it.
  - Mineral wool insulation (Rockwool™ is one brand) is heavy and is often used for sound deadening
  - Mass Loaded Vinyl is often hung on one side of the drywall or the other.
  - There are types of drywall that are heavier that are designed for sound proofing. 5/8" drywall is heavier than 1/2" so it's an option. Multiple layers are an option.
  - There is "green glue" that's often used between drywall layers. I'm not sure of its properties or exact name, but I've seen the term bandied about.
- Absorption

  - Sound absorbing foams are available that will help reduce the sound that hits a wall and is, thus, transferred through it.

I'm sure I've missed a *lot* of details and info. I really recommend browsing the linked questions.

Comment: Anything solid and rigid is bad. If you have two solid things, try separating them with something "squishy", i.e. don't put wood on wood, sepereate them with some foam/putty/silicone/whatever, something that remains sort of soft. Don't forget about the floor, a 2t CNC on metal legs, standing on a concrete floor, will transmit more noise through the floor than air/wall (same for dust collection on the roof).

Answer (score 1):

If you are concerned about the general noise in your shop area then you should worry about sound proof/deadening the room - which can be difficult and expensive.

If you are worried about the noise the Avid CNC machine will make consider building a soundproof/sound reduction box to put the Avid CNC machine in. Searching for "soundproof cnc enclosure" will provide you with many ideas.
[image]